# how to get the current LoggedInUser from a JS file, not in a controller

Tags: express

In my express app, I need to get the loggedin user to get his data...

But I am in a JS file on the client, not on a controller where i can access it easily via the req,res?

What is the correct way to get the logged in user info when im on a JS file on the client?

I could, a data atributte on the dom  with the slug of the logged in user and then send a get request to my controller that gets user by slug and then i would have it...

however that feels kind of dirty.. any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data via `res.locals` object from server to client. But you can not get this data as an obj, because the server always sends a rendered HTML file to client. So what you should do is have it in an input element.

SERVER

```
res.locals.yourData = ...;
```

CLIENT

```
input(type="hidden", value={yourData})
```

Another way (render it as javascript)

```
script(type="javascript/text")
     const data = yourData;
```

If not working, stringify the data (JSON), and parse it in client to retrieve the data.